# Platform independent memory mapped [file] IO

Tags: c++, boost, cross-platform, shared-memory, mmap

I've spent some time investigating memory mapped IO for an application I'm working on.  I have some very large (TB scale) files, and I want to map segments from them into memory, for both reading and writing, making maximum use of OS-level caching.  The software I'm writing needs to work under Unix/Linux and Windows... performance is critical.

I've discovered `boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source` and `boost::iostreams::mapped_file_sink`, which provide most of the facilities I'm looking for.  The facilities I'd like, but haven't found are:

- Forcing a synchronisation of written data to disk ( `msync`(2) on Unix; `FlushViewOfFile` on Windows)
- Locking of files to prevent two processes attempting to write the same file at the same time (or read while the file is still being written..)
- Controlling attributes of the file at creation time (Unix)

Can I do these things using `"boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp"`?  Are there other platform independent libraries that would better suit my requirements?  Must I develop my own cross-platform library to get this flexibility?

Comment: BTW, "memory mapped I/O" generally refers to reading I/O ports using addresses (a.k.a. memory mapped) (like using a pointer) rather than using special processor I/O instructions.

Comment: Fair point. I'm talking about memory mapped file I/O [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file ] - and have edited the title to reflect this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at boost::interprocess and boost::interprocess::file_mapping. They have everything you need.

[boost::interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess.html)

[boost::interprocess::file_mapping](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/file_mapping.html)

Comment: You might be right... but, with boost::interprocess, I can't see how I can (straightforwardly) establish access the data in OS-page-sized chunks...

Comment: @aSteve, this library supports memory mapped files, see: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_mapped_files

Comment: Yes, boost::interprocess supports (managed) memory mapped files... "managed" in this context implies that space in the file is accessed "as if" by malloc().  Obviously valuable for inter-process-communication, but I require a more basic "unmanaged?" approach for "raw" IO. I need a function that returns a pointer to a mapped block containing an arbitrary file offset. The boost::iostreams::mapped_file_* interfaces are ideal here... though they don't offer the same flexibility for synchronisation/locking. I've read the interprocess docs - I can't see how to use interprocess for "raw" mapped IO.

Comment: Update... I now realise you meant that I should use boost::interprocess::file_mapping - and this class makes perfect sense.

Comment: @aSteve, sorry, I thought you'd explore the library once you were aware of it! :) it seems you have now! ;)

Answer (score 2):

This question is pretty old but the top hit on google. So I'll add some other libs I know of.

[mio](https://github.com/mandreyel/mio)
Cross-platform C++11 header-only library for memory mapped file IO.

- Seems simple and straightforward, but potentially abandoned.

[llfio](https://github.com/ned14/llfio)
P1031 low level file i/o and filesystem library for the C++ standard.

- The mother of all io libraries it seems. Has gone through boost peer review (aka torture). Is proposed as an addition to C++ standard library.

I can also vouch for boost::interprocess, I've used it to great effect in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I tried to see what is happening when using boost's memory mapped io for writing into sparse files, knowing about UNIXs inability to provide something like structured exception handling as available on Windows since antiquity.

I found out, that even the originators of boost cannot work around this:

They are allocating disk space for the entire size of the mapped memory, making the file non-sparse. Of course this takes time and diskspace.

Comment: Interesting. I've been using Boost Interprocess with sparse mapped files since antiquity as well, and they work just fine (I promise I never actually had petabytes of RAM nor disk :)). I'm also not quite sure how structured exceptions come into that.